# R knitr save_kable plain html output

Tags: r, knitr, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to export a set of data frames to HTML files. I tried the following configuration:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

writeDFtoHTML<-function(df,path){
    df%>%
        kable(escape = F) %>%
        kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed","basic"),font_size = 9,full_width = F, position = "left")%>%
        save_kable(file = path, self_contained = F,bs_theme = "simplex", extra_dependencies = NULL)

}
```

I call the writeDFtoHTML function from within a for loop and I write the df data frames in different folders for specification.
The problem is that in each path folder save_kable creates a lib dir containing JavaScript libraries:

lib/bootstrap-3.3.5

lib/jquery-1.11.3

lib/kePrint-0.0.1

Those libraries weigh a lot: about 4MB for each df folder. I have 50 df to save, one for folder, and this makes over 200MB output. Impossible since I need a simple, plain, static HTML.

Another issue is that save_kable creates those lib dirs again and again each time I export my data frames, regardless if the lib folders already exist.

Is there a method I can use to force save_kable to create a plain html file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `self_contained=TRUE` as an argument.